# The absolute center for nilpotent group of class $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

> Let $G=\langle a,b,c : a^9=b^3=1,c^3=a^3,ab=ba^4,ac=cab^{-1},cb=bc\rangle$.
>   Find $L(G)$ where $L(G)=\{x\in G:\alpha(x)=x \; \forall\alpha\in\text{Aut}(G)\}$

By using GAP, the following are the information I have:
(i) $G$ is of size $81$.
(ii)$Z(G)=\langle a^3\rangle$.
(iii) $G$ is nilpotent group of class $3$.
(iv) $|\text{Aut}(G)|=486$

By using the commutator notation, $G$ can be also written as $$\langle a,b,c : a^9=b^3=1,c^3=a^3,[a,b]=a^3,[c,a]=b,[b,c]=1\rangle$$

It can be easily checked that $L(G)\leq Z(G)$. Hence $L(G)=1$ or $\langle a^3 \rangle$. So the problem is solved if one can find an automorphism that does not fix $a^3$ or show that $a^3$ is fixed under every automorphism.

If I want to show the latter part, let $\alpha\in \text{Aut}(G)$, then $\alpha(a)=a^ib^jc^k$. Hence $\alpha(a^3)=(a^ib^jc^k)^3$. Here the commutator identities cannot be used since $G$ is nilpotent of class $3$. So I can't find the restriction on the values of $i,j,k$.

Any hints or idea would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It might help to notice that since the center is characteristic $\alpha(a^3) \in \langle a^3\rangle$.

Comment: Let $\operatorname{Aut} G \curvearrowright G$ be group action by evaluation. Then the class equation would be $$|G| = |L(G)| + \sum_{\operatorname{Aut} G \cdot x} \frac{|\operatorname{Aut} G|}{|(\operatorname{Aut} G)_x|}$$ where $\operatorname{Aut} G \cdot x$ are distinct orbits with size $> 1$. This may also help.

Comment: So $L(G) = \langle\alpha^3\rangle$ if there is no index $2$ stabilizer subgroup with respect to the above group action. An index $2$ subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut} G$ is also the unique Sylow-$3$ subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut} G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $z=a^3=c^3$, the map $\phi$ with $a \mapsto a^2$, $b \mapsto bz$, $c \mapsto c^2z$, $z \mapsto z^2$ extends to an automorphism of $G$.

I found this automorphism by computer, but it is not difficult to verify by hand that it preserves the group relations, and hence extends to an automorphism.

For example, consider the relation $c^{-1}ac=ab^{-1} = ab^2$. Then $\phi(a)\phi(b^2) = a^2b^2 z^2$, whereas $\phi(c^{-1})\phi(a)\phi(c) = z^{-1}c^{-2}a^2c^2z=c^{-2}a^2c^2$.

Now $c^{-2}ac^2 = ab^2b^2= ab$, so $c^{-2}a^2c^2=abab=a^2b^2z^2$, because $ba=abz^2$.

Comment: Sorry for late reply as it takes time to verify every group relations. So under this automorphism, $a^3,a^6$ are not fixed, hence we can conclude that $L(G)=1$. By the way, may I know in details how you find this automorphism? I really need this method to solve the similar problem for other groups. Thanks.

Comment: You said that you have computed the automorphism group $A$  of $G$ in GAP. Just look at the actions of the generators of $A$ on the elements of $G$ and you will find at least one of them maps $a^3$ to $a^{-3}$. That's what I did (although I used Magma rather than GAP).